# Why can I not use toString() on a Number unless I declare it as a variable first?

Tags: javascript, numbers

For example:

```
var num = 5;
num.toString(2); // Returns the binary representation 101
```

But if I do

```
5.toString(2); // Error
```

I thought that the second example should work because it seems fine with strings. For example:

```
// BOTH WORK

var str = 'hi';
str.toUpperCase(); // Returns 'HI';

'hi'.toUpperCase(); // Returns 'HI';
```

Comment: my guess is that it thinks a the `.` as a decimal point and expects another number to follow not text, doing it like `5..toString(2)` works

Comment: Explanation is given in the duped question. You can also fix this by leaving a space after the number, like this `5 .toString(2)`

Comment: more versions: `5['toString']()`, `5..toString()`, `(5).toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a low-level syntactic problem. The token syntax for numbers includes the possibility of fractional parts following a decimal point. That syntax takes precedence over the overloaded meaning of `.` as a property reference operator. When the parser sees `5.` it expects to see a fractional part of the number. Non-digits are considered an error.

If you want to use the `.` as a property reference, you have to satisfy the token grammar and encase the number in some construct that will allow the parser to see `.` the way you want:

```
var str = (5).toString();
```

There, your numeric constant is wrapped in parentheses. The `.` following the parentheses can be nothing other than a property reference operator, so the call to `.toString()` works as intended.

Comment: damn awesome. Such amazing answer, much wow.